# Python : for loop inside wsgi script

Tags: python, wsgi

I wanted to embed a forloop inside html part of wsgi script.

```
my_list=[1,2,3]
def my_function(environ,start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    return ['''
            <html>
                 <body>
                      for i in my_list:
                       <p>
                          i
                       </p>
                <body>
            </html>
           ''']
```

How to make the python code run inside that wsgi response?

Comment: Congrats! Do you have a question? Hurry, or you'll get lots of downvotes!

Comment: Why would you do it inside of a string?

Comment: I am not able to find using python code inside html without templates and it is question for me.sorry inexperienced with wsgi.

Comment: how to escape that for loop and make it run as a python code inside that html string.

Comment: You don't. Do it outside of the string. **Just like you would in any other Python program.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do, is what template languages or libraries help us do. Since you don't want to use any template language/library, you need to construct the needed strings your self. For this particular instance, you can do the following:

```
s = '''\
<html>
    <body>{list}
    </body>
</html>'''

item = '''
        <p>
            {0}
        </p>\
'''
print(s.format(list="".join(map(item.format, [1, 2, 3]))))
```

Result:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            1
        </p>
        <p>
            2
        </p>
        <p>
            3
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```